# CLGeocoder completionHandler with ARC always crashes (EXEC_BAD_ACCESS) in the completion handler block

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I’ve got a problem using the `[CLGeocoder geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:]` method to gecode an `Address string`. Running on iOS 5 the app always crashes `(EXEC_BAD_ACCESS)` in the `completion handler block`.

```
- (void)geocodeLocationComponents:(NSDictionary *)location
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    NSString *searchString = [self stringFromLocation:location
                                             forStage:self.stage];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:searchString
                 completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                     self.stage++;
                     if (!error &&
                         placemarks &&
                         placemarks.count > 0) {
                         [self.delegate geocoder:self
                    didFinishCodingWithPlacemark:[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]];
                     } else {
                         ...
                     }
                 }];
}
```

Looking for a solution, i figured out, that this is caused by calling self in the block. The mentioned solution (for ARC!) was to create a weak reference, like that

```
__weak MyClass *blockSaveSelf = self;
```

and calling that in the block. I tried it but this reference is always nil.
By the way, why does this only occurs, running on iOS5? (There are no problems with iOS 6)

Comment: If it is `nil` then that means the class creating the block has been deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking for a solution, i figured out, that this is caused by calling
>   self in the block.

This doesn't make a bit of sense. First, the usual issue with `self` in a block is that it retains `self` and `self` retains the block, causing a retain cycle. Here, there is no retain cycle, because `self` does not have a strong reference to the geocoder. And second, even if there were a retain cycle, it would cause a leak, NEVER a crash.

Your code has many problems, including that nothing has a strong reference to the geocoder after this function returns, so it probably gets deallocated (what happens to the geocoding that is started, I have no idea).

Also, an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is likely a message to a deallocated instance, so enabling zombies would be a first step to get more information about what deallocated thing is being messaged.